# How to add up Object.values using ```v-model```

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli, v-model

I am trying to add up an `Object.value`, having its adding value bound to the number being inputed in my `input` through a `v-model` to  total number.

When I input any number then use the `@click` listener the behaviour is odd, it keeps concatenating whatever I am firing, treating the result as a `String` instead of a `Number`.

Interesting that if I comment out the `input` `tag`, hence removing the `v-model` and changing the value on `this.shared[2].value` to any number greater then `0`, the desired behaviour will occur.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="number" v-model="shares[2].value">
    <p>{{this.shares[0].value}}</p>
    <button class="btn btn-primary"
            @click="result">Sum An Object Value</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

  export default {
    data(){
      return {
        shares: [
          {id: 'BMW', value: 0},
          {id: 'Ford', value: 0},
          {id:'Apple', value: 0}
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      result(){
        this.shares[0].value += this.shares[2].value
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

How could I get the appropriate behaviour here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#number):

> If you want user input to be automatically typecast as a number, you can add the number modifier to your v-model managed inputs:

```
<input v-model.number="age" type="number">
```

> This is often useful, because even with type="number", the value of HTML input elements always returns a string. If the value cannot be parsed with parseFloat(), then the original value is returned.

Comment: thanks for this refresher. I have been studying vue and its overwhelming sometimes, specially when I forget this details after modules and plus modules of contents =)